# Excel VBA, error code 1004 while using running "Index" formula

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a section of macro with below code inside, however having issues below:

Code:

```
Dim OldSMIWB As Workbook
...
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=INDEX('[" & OldSMIWB.Name & "]SMI Data'!C1:C60,MATCH(RC1,'[" & OldSMIWB.Name & "]SMI Data'!C1,0),MATCH(R1C,'[" & OldSMIWB.Name & "]SMI Data'!R1,0))"
...
```

Error message:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Can anyone help me out?

Appreciated!

Tony

Comment: What is the value of `OldSMIWB`?

Comment: You have `.FormulaR1C1`, but then use a non-`R1C1` style text here "`"]SMI Data'!C1:C60`".

Comment: Use Debug.Print or MsgBox to see if the formula string is correct. To do so declare a string variable and assign formula string to it and then use debug.print or msgbox as suggested.

Comment: What is the value of OldSMIWB? – Máté Juhász >>>>> oldsmiwb value is complicate, but oldsmiwb.name = "SMI (Excess) inventory review Q1'17 - WK13 - Mar 31.xlsx"

Comment: You have .FormulaR1C1, but then use a non-R1C1 style text here ""]SMI Data'!C1:C60". – BruceWayne >>>>>>>>>> the C1 = column 1, not the cell C1.

Comment: Use Debug.Print or MsgBox to see if the formula string is correct. To do so declare a string variable and assign formula string to it and then use debug.print or msgbox as suggested. – sktneer >>>>>>>>>> I'm using "Add watch " to debug, so far no issues found, all string seems right, not sure if the formula syntax is correct.

Comment: Haha, oh duh (regarding my statement).  How did you define `OldSMIWB`?  You may not need the `Name` part depending.... Perhaps you need the `'` around it since it has an apostrophe? Try writing your formula **in a cell**, then choose `R1C1` formula style in Options. Then basically take that and throw it into VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Because your workbook name includes an apostrophe (`'`) it will need to have the apostrophe escaped when including it in your formula:

```
Dim OldSMIWBName As String
OldSMIWBName = Replace(OldSMIWB.Name, "'", "''")
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX('[" & OldSMIWBName & "]SMI Data'!C1:C60,MATCH(RC1,'[" & OldSMIWBName & "]SMI Data'!C1,0),MATCH(R1C,'[" & OldSMIWBName & "]SMI Data'!R1,0))"
```